# Good PDF to HTML Converter for Mobiles

Tags: html, pdf, converters

We are having Multiple PDF which have account tables and balance sheet within it. We have tried many Converters but the result is not satisfactory. Can anybody please suggest any good converter that would replicated the contents of PDF to Exact structure in HTML. IF any paid Converter is there please suggest me .

```
  This is the PDF we want to convert and Show in html "http://www.marico.com/html/investor/pdf/Quarterly_Updates/Consolidated%20Financial%20Results%20-%20Q3FY11.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into this? http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/

It's open source as well, so it's free and can be modified if necessary.

There's even a demo showing the before PDF and the after HTML version. Not bad if you ask me.

If you're having issues specifically with tables in PDFs, perhaps the issue are the table themselves and whatever program is being used to generate them. Not all PDFs are created equal.

**ALSO:** *Be aware that all PDFs that I've created and come across over the years have had lots of issues when it comes to copy/pasting blocks/lines of text that have other blocks/lines of text at equal or higher height on any given page. I think Acrobat lacks the ability to define a "sequence order" of what block is selected after what (or most programs don't use it properly), so the system sorta moves from a top-down, left-to-right way of selecting content.....even if that means jumping over large blank areas or grabbing lines from multiple columns at once when you wouldn't expect it. This may be part of your tabular data issue. Your weak link here is the PDF format itself and I think perhaps you may be expecting too much from it. Turning anything into a PDF is pretty much a one-way street, especially when you start putting lots of editable text into it.*

Comment: yes thank u for reply but i have looked into that link and i couldnt get the desired output from it

Comment: hi thanks for answer but i need to convert this PDF in its original structure [link](http://www.marico.com/html/investor/pdf/Quarterly_Updates/Consolidated%20Financial%20Results%20-%20Q3FY11.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://www.jpedal.org/html_index.php - there is also a free online version

Comment: Its 10k... I'd happily develop one for half that